# Проблемы со схлопывающимися отступами и стилизацией формы

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Всем здравствуйте. Нужно решение для двух проблем:

**Во-первых**, помогите, пожалуйста с отступами, которые образовались между двумя контейнерами (после кнопки "Find out more about us"). Полагаю, это проблема схлопывающихся отступов.

**Во-вторых**, подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы расположить надпись "Full-time" и соответствующий ей checkbox ровно (!) в один ряд, а под ним "Part-time/Casual/Freelance" с уже его checkbox. То есть чтобы смотрелось нормально, а не вот так в кашу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 568px) {
    body, ul, h1 {
        font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    header {
        height: 700px;
        background: url(bg-img.png) no-repeat center top / cover;
    }
    .wrapper {
        position: relative;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    .menu {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 30%;
        height: 100vh;
        background-color: #fff;
        transition: 0.5s;
        transform: translateX(-100%);
    }
    .menu-active {
        transform: translateX(30%);
    }
    .menu-list {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-items: center;
        flex-direction: column;
        height: 50%;
    }
    .menu-list li {
        list-style-type: none;
    }
    .menu-list a {
        text-decoration: none;
        text-transform: uppercase;
    }
    .menu-btn {
        position: absolute;
        top: 10px;
        right: -35px;
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
        background-color: black;
    }
    .search-form h1 {
        font-size: 1.9rem;
        font-style: italic;
        font-weight: 100;
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff;
        margin-top: 150px;
    }
    form {
        width: 180px;
        margin: 50px auto;
    }
    form input {
        border-style: none;
        height: 7vh;
        width: 55vw;
    }
    input[type="checkbox"] {
        width: 30px;
        height: 30px;
    }
    form select {
        border-style: none;
    }
    .button {
        color: white;
        display: block;
        padding: 15px;
        border-style: none;
        margin: 50px auto;
        background-color: #4acaff;
    }
    .container-1 {
        position: relative;
        background-color: #f5f5f5;
        padding-top: 70px;
    }
    .inner-container-1 {
        text-align: center;
        margin-top: 70px;
    }
    .container-1 span {
        font-size: 2rem;
        font-style: italic;
    }
    .container-1 h1 {
        position: relative;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
    }
    .container-1 .blue {
        position: absolute;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        bottom: 0;
        left: 50%;
        width: 140px;
        height: 5px;
        background-color: #4acaff;
    }
    .container-1 p {
        font-size: 1rem;
        margin-top: 50px;
    }
    .btn {
        display: block;
        padding: 10px;
        color: #6cd3fd;
        text-decoration: none;
        font-weight: bold;
        background-color: #fff;
        border: 3px solid #6cd3fd;
        margin: 50px auto;
        border-radius: 15px;
        width: 45vw;
    }
    .container-2 {
        height: 300vh;
        background-color: #131c25;
    }
    .inner-container-2 {
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Freebie</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="menu">
                <a href="#" class="menu-btn"></a>
                <nav class="menu-list">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Employers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="search-form">
            <h1>I'm looking for...</h1>
            <form>
                <input type="text" name="job-searching" placeholder="Enter a job description">
                        <label for="full-time" class="light">Full Time</label><br>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="full-time" value="full_time" name="type-of-work">
                        <label for="part-time" class="light">Part time / Casual / Freelance</label>
                        <input type="checkbox" id="part-time" value="part_time" name="type-of-work">
                <select name="location" placeholder="Select your location">
                    <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
                    <option value="the-USA">The USA</option>
                    <option value="canada">Canada</option>
                    <option value="germany">Germany</option>
                    <option value="france">France</option>
                    <option value="great-britain">Great Britain</option>
                </select>
            </form>
            <button class="button" type="submit">Search</button>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="container-1">
        <div class="inner-container-1">
                    <span>We're leaders in</span>
                    <h1><span class="blue"></span>Creative Digital Recruitment</h1>
                    <p>Based in Surry Hills, the creative hub of Sydney we are surrounded by creativity<br/>
                            and that reflects on the type of jobs we recruit for.</p>
                            <a class="btn" href="#">Find out more about us!</a>
        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="container-2">
            <div class="inner-container-2">
                <span>Subscribe to our Job Seeker Mailing List</span>
            </div>
        </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Что бы label и input выровнять на одной линии я объеденил их в один тег параграфа и стилизовал на flexbox

Схлопнутые наружные отступы - это изестный хак , задаём border-bottom:1px solid transparent и тогда ваш блок встанет до самого низа ...

Рабочий пример в песочнице: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/VRrEYo

> Так как медиазапрос не совпадает с размером сниппета то работать здесь
>   это не будет ...

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 568px) {
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  html,
  body,
  ul,
  h1 {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  header {
    background: url(https://roomester.ru/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/dizayn_ofisa_3_06233929.jpg) no-repeat center top / cover, #34336dad;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
    background-blend-mode: darken;
  }
  .wrapper {
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  .menu {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 30%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: #fff;
    transition: 0.5s;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  .menu-active {
    transform: translateX(30%);
  }
  .menu-list {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 50%;
  }
  .menu-list li {
    list-style-type: none;
  }
  .menu-list a {
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  .menu-btn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: -35px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: black;
  }
  .search-form h1 {
    font-size: 1.9rem;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: 150px;
  }
  form {
    width: 180px;
    margin: 50px auto;
  }
  form input {
    border-style: none;
    height: 7vh;
    width: 55vw;
  }
  input[type="checkbox"] {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
  }
  form select {
    border-style: none;
  }
  .button {
    color: white;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px;
    border-style: none;
    margin: 50px auto;
    background-color: #4acaff;
  }
  .container-1 {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    padding-top: 70px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
  }
  .inner-container-1 {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 70px;
  }
  .container-1 span {
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-style: italic;
  }
  .container-1 h1 {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
  }
  .container-1 .blue {
    position: absolute;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    width: 140px;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #4acaff;
  }
  .container-1 p {
    font-size: 1rem;
    margin-top: 50px;
  }
  .btn {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #6cd3fd;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 3px solid #6cd3fd;
    margin: 50px auto;
    border-radius: 15px;
    width: 45vw;
  }
  .container-2 {
    height: 300vh;
    background-color: #131c25;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
  .inner-container-2 {
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
  }
  form p {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  }
  form label,
  form input {
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #fbfbfb;
  }
  form p {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 0 4px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <title>Freebie</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="menu">
        <a href="#" class="menu-btn"></a>
        <nav class="menu-list">
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Jobs</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Clients</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Employers</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="search-form">
      <h1>I'm looking for...</h1>
      <form>
        <input type="text" name="job-searching" placeholder="Enter a job description">
        <p>
          <label for="full-time" class="light">Full Time</label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="full-time" value="full_time" name="type-of-work">
        </p>
        <p>
          <label for="part-time" class="light">Parttime/Casual/Freelance</label>
          <input type="checkbox" id="part-time" value="part_time" name="type-of-work">
        </p>
        <select name="location" placeholder="Select your location">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Select your option</option>
          <option value="the-USA">The USA</option>
          <option value="canada">Canada</option>
          <option value="germany">Germany</option>
          <option value="france">France</option>
          <option value="great-britain">Great Britain</option>
        </select>
      </form>
      <button class="button" type="submit">Search</button>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="container-1">
    <div class="inner-container-1">
      <span>We're leaders in</span>
      <h1><span class="blue"></span>Creative Digital Recruitment</h1>
      <p>Based in Surry Hills, the creative hub of Sydney we are surrounded by creativity<br/> and that reflects on the type of jobs we recruit for.</p>
      <a class="btn" href="#">Find out more about us!</a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="container-2">
    <div class="inner-container-2">
      <span>Subscribe to our Job Seeker Mailing List</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```